# Understanding open set in product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ are topological spaces and $U\times V\subset X\times Y$ be a subset where $X\times Y$ with product topology. If $U\times V$ is open then $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $X, Y$ respectively?

I know that if $U\times V$ is open then $U\times V =\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\times V_i$ where $U_i\subset X$: basic open set and $V_i\subset Y$: basic open set. But I'm not sure this implies the above statement. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s true. Let $x\in U$; we’ll show that $x$ has an open nbhd contained in $U$. To do so, let $y\in V$; then $\langle x,y\rangle\in U\times V$, so there are basic open sets $B_x$ in $X$ and $B_y$ in $Y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in B_x\times B_y\subseteq U\times V$. Thus, $B_x$ is an open nbhd of $x$ contained in $U$. If we do this for each $x\in U$, we see that $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}B_x$, so $U$ is open in $X$. The argument for $V$ is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Using that images of functions commute with unions:

$$U = \pi_1[U \times V]= \pi_1[\bigcup_i U_i \times V_i] = \bigcup_i \pi_1[U_i \times V_i] = \bigcup_i U_i$$

and $U$ is open as the union of the $U_i$. W can do the same for $V$ with $\pi_2$, the other projection.